# Can't change papersize even with geometry

Tags: geometry

I'm writing my thesis. To be printed, the paper must have a height of 24cm and a width of 16cm. The margins must be of 2cm.

```
\geometry{paperheight=24cm,paperwidth=16cm,centering,textheight=20cm,textwidth=12cm}
```

The first version that I've submitted in April had the right dimensions. Now, I have to modify the text. When I start to modify the text, without changing anything in the packages that I use, the compilation gives me the right textwidth and textheight BUT not the right paper size (it seems to be an a4paper or something like this. Even by changing the paperheight and paperwidth in the option of the geometry package, nothing is changing.
The log file gives me:

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: dvips
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* hratio: 1:1
* vratio: 1:1
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(56.9055pt, 341.43306pt, 56.90552pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(56.9055pt, 569.05511pt, 56.90552pt)
* \paperwidth=455.24408pt
* \paperheight=682.86613pt
* \textwidth=341.43306pt
* \textheight=569.05511pt
* \oddsidemargin=-15.36449pt
* \evensidemargin=-15.36447pt
* \topmargin=-45.43198pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=18.06749pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=25.29494pt
* \marginparwidth=125.0pt
* \marginparsep=7.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
```

Does anybody know what is wrong with my latex file ?

Thank you !

Comment: Which engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using TeXMaker 4.4.1 with MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: Yes, but pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, ...?

Comment: Oups sorry: pdfTeX.

Comment: `2.54cm=1in=72.27pt` so `24cm=682.866...pt` you're fine

Comment: Are you really using pdftex? The code above said that the detected driver is dvips. If you are forcing geometry to use the wrong driver the page size will be wrong.

Comment: @touhami: The code shows the \paperwidth and \paperheight, this doesn't say anything about the pdf page size.

Comment: @touhami: I know that the conversion between pt to cm gives me the good paperwidth and paperheigth but the result is not good (https://www.dropbox.com/s/u23w5pumg9138l4/Test.pdf?dl=0)!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I compile my document like this: LaTex -> BibLaTeX -> LaTeX -> LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf

Comment: How current is your miktex?

Comment: Miktex 2.9 installed on late July 2015 with all the installed package updated yesterday

Comment: Check with the admin update manager if there is a dvips update.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: It works! But I had to change the server location before to have any update available. Thanks for your help :-)